# Use jQuery click to handle anchor onClick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, anchor

I have a set of dynamically generated anchor tags in a for loop as follows:

```
<div id = "solTitle"> <a href = "#"  id = "' + tagId + '" onClick = "openSolution();"> ' + solTitle + '</a></div> <br>';
```

Once this code is executed the html output for one of the case would look like:

```
<div id = "solTitle"> <a href = "#"  id = "solution0" onClick = "openSolution();">Solution0 </a></div> <br>

<div id = "solTitle"> <a href = "#"  id = "solution1" onClick = "openSolution();">Solution1 </a></div> <br>
```

Now I want different texts to be displayed on clicking the above links.
openSolution() looks like this:

```
function openSolution() {
    alert('here');
    $('#solTitle a').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert('here in');
        var divId = 'summary' + $(this).attr('id');

        document.getElementById(divId).className = '';

    });
}
```

When I execute it and click on either of the  links, the flow doesnot come inside the jquery click handler.  I checked it by the above alerts used. It only displays the alert - 'here' and not the alert - 'here in'. 
On clicking the link second time, everything works perfectly with correct value of divId.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The first time you click the link, the `openSolution` function is executed. That function binds the `click` event handler to the link, but it won't execute it. The second time you click the link, the `click` event handler will be executed.

What you are doing seems to kind of defeat the point of using jQuery in the first place. Why not just bind the click event to the elements in the first place:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#solTitle a").click(function() {
        //Do stuff when clicked
    });
});
```

This way you don't need `onClick` attributes on your elements.

It also looks like you have multiple elements with the same `id` value ("solTitle"), which is invalid. You would need to find some other common characteristic (`class` is usually a good option). If you change all occurrences of `id="solTitle"` to `class="solTitle"`, you can then use a class selector:

```
$(".solTitle a")
```

Since duplicate `id` values is invalid, the code will not work as expected when facing multiple copies of the same `id`. What tends to happen is that the first occurrence of the element with that `id` is used, and all others are ignored.

Comment: that won't be valid since the #soltitle is being repeated

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - I have mentioned that in the last paragraph. I guess it could be a bit clearer though, thanks.

Comment: This answer is obsolete nowadays. jQuery today uses `.on('click', function() {` instead of `.click(function() {`

Answer (score 13):

Lets take an anchor tag with an onclick event, that calls a Javascript function.

```
<a href="#" onClick="showDiv(1);">1</a>
```

Now in javascript write the below code

```
function showDiv(pageid)
{
   alert(pageid);
}
```

This will show you an alert of "1"....

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. The question was how to use jQuery to handle the click. Your answer only works with vanilla javascript and not jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, but it made me think. This was easier in my case.

Comment: The onclick event has a lowercase c, not an uppercase.

Answer (score 5):

The HTML should look like:

```
<div class="solTitle"> <a href="#"  id="solution0">Solution0 </a></div>
<div class="solTitle"> <a href="#"  id="solution1">Solution1 </a></div>

<div id="summary_solution0" style="display:none" class="summary">Summary solution0</div>
<div id="summary_solution1" style="display:none" class="summary">Summary solution1</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".solTitle a").live('click',function(e){
        var contentId = "summary_" + $(this).attr('id');
        $(".summary").hide();
        $("#" + contentId).show();
    });
});
```

See the Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kmendes/4G9UF/

Comment: Note that `live()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9. The recommended method to attach event listeners is `on()`.

ref: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class = "solTitle"> <a href = "#"  id = "solution0" onClick = "openSolution();">Solution0 </a></div> <br>

<div class= "solTitle"> <a href = "#"  id = "solution1" onClick = "openSolution();">Solution1 </a></div> <br>



$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.solTitle a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('here in');
         var divId = 'summary' +$(this).attr('id');

        document.getElementById(divId).className = ''; /* or $('#'+divid).removeAttr('class'); */

    });
 });
```

I changed few things:

1. remove the onclick attr and  bind click event inside the document.ready
2. changed solTitle to be an ID to a CLASS: id cant be repeated

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple time the same ID for elements. It is meant to be unique.

Use a class and make your IDs unique:

```
<div class="solTitle" id="solTitle1"> <a href = "#"  id = "solution0" onClick = "openSolution();">Solution0 </a></div>
```

And use the class selector:

```
$('.solTitle a').click(function(evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();
    alert('here in');
    var divId = 'summary' + this.id.substring(0, this.id.length-1);

    document.getElementById(divId).className = ''; 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning an `onclick` event inside an function.
That means once the function has executed once, the second `onclick` event is assigned to the element as well.

> Either assign the function `onclick` or use jquery `click()`.

There's no need to have both