# Use jquery to handle click() and debug jquery in chrome

Tags: jquery, html

Concept:

I have a dynamic form in struts2 java, when user click the "Add new Edu" link, a jquery function will be fired to extend the dynamic form. Here is my jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script language="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Education List</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="/save" method="POST">   
    <div class="educationForm">
        <c:if test="${ (not empty educations) }"> 
            <c:if test="${ fn:length(educations) ge 1 }">
                <c:forEach items="${educations}" var="edu" varStatus="status">
                    <div class="educations">                    
                        <label>Position</label><input type="text" name="educations[${ status.index }].index" value="${ educations[status.index].index }" /><br/>
                        <label>School</label><input type="text" name="educations[${ status.index }].school" value="${ educations[status.index ].school }" /><br/>
                        <label>Degree</label><input type="text" name="educations[${ status.index }].degree" value="${ educations[status.index ].degree }" /><br/>
                        <label>GPA</label><input type="text" name="educations[${ status.index }].scored" value="${ educations[status.index ].scored }" /><br/>
                        <label>Start Date</label><input type="text" name="educations[${ status.index }].startDate" value="${ educations[status.index].startDate }" /><br/>
                        <label>End Date</label><input type="text" name="educations[${ status.index }].endDate" value="${ educations[status.index].endDate }" /><br/>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>        
            </c:if>         
        </c:if>
        <div class="educations">
            <label>Position</label><input type="text" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].index" value="${fn:length(educations) + 1}" /><br/>
            <label>School</label><input type="text" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].school" /><br/>
            <label>Degree</label><input type="text" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].degree" /><br/>
            <label>GPA</label><input type="text" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].scored" /><br/>
            <label>Start Date</label><input type="text" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].startDate" /><br/>
            <label>End Date</label><input type="text" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].endDate" /><br/>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <a href="#" id="addButton">Add new Edu</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />        
</s:form>

<div class="template_educations" style="display:none">
    <div class="educations">
        <label>Position</label><input type="text" name="educations[_X_].index" /><br/>
        <label>School</label><input type="text" name="educations[_X_].school" /><br/>
        <label>Degree</label><input type="text" name="educations[_X_].degree" /><br/>
        <label>GPA</label><input type="text" name="educations[_X_].scored" /><br/>
        <label>Start Date</label><input type="text" name="educations[_X_].startDate" /><br/>
        <label>End Date</label><input type="text" name="educations[_X_].endDate" /><br/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Common.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addButton").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".educationForm").append($(".template_educations").html);
        $(".educationForm").children(".educations").last().children("input").each(function(){           
            var count = $(".educationForm").children(".education").length();
            var value = $(this).attr("name");
            value.replace("_X_", count + 1);
            $(this).attr("name", value);
        });         
    });
});
```

Problems:

- It seem like the jquery function does not work properly. I tried some suggest in [Use jquery click to handle anchor onClick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908191/use-jquery-click-to-handle-anchor-onclick) but it didn't help.
- Usually, I use chrome to debug javascript. But in this case, the js file doesn't appear in sources tab of chrome develpoing tools so I can't debug it in chrome.

Any suggestion for my problems?

Comment: first upgrade jquery to 1.9.1 there are lot of bug fixes

Comment: have you tried using Fire Bug on FF?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'll try your suggestion, will feedback asap

Comment: @scornork Ok, I'll give it a try too

Comment: It sounds like you don't have jquery loading in at all if chrome isn't seeing it. That would explain why the click handler isn't firing.

Comment: @DoanCuong checkk your network tab in developer tools to see whether jquery is loaded

Comment: @ArunPJohny No, it didn't

Comment: @DoanCuong check whether you have placed the jquery file correctly

Comment: In include jquery using a cdn `<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: I think the problem is in `script` tag `language="text/javascript"` is invalid please try `language="javascript"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script tag definition is invalid, the language attribute should have the value `javascript` instead if `text/javascript>`.

```
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or just omit the language attribute completely.

Comment: It works. Thank for your help. Now I'm trying to change the version to 1.9.1 to fix some bugs :D