# jquery function is not called when clicking on link

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to call a jquery function when clicking on a link, but it doesn't work, the function is not called at all...

Function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#notif').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                        alert('test');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "inc/showNotif.php",
                dataType: "html",
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('.displayNotif').html(result);
                    console.log(result)
                }
            });

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Link:

```
<a href="#" id="notif" data-id="<?php echo $_SESSION['ID']; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="icon-bell2"></i>
                            <span class="visible-xs-inline-block position-right">Activity</span>
                            <span class="status-mark border-orange-400"></span>
                        </a>
```

## EDIT

I discovered that the code between  tags doesn't execute at all, not even if I remove the onclick event.

## EDIT 2

The issue is `$(document).ready(function ()` the code works without it, but why?

## SOLVED

Issue was some jquery errors preventing document.rady

Comment: Hello I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908191/use-jquery-click-to-handle-anchor-onclick) can help you !!

Comment: just remove href="#" or stop event propagation

Comment: you could also replace your `href="#"` for `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: @Nicolas I did what you've said and the jquery function is still not being called, I don't think the href is the issue because it used to work :/ something else must be but I can't see it

Comment: Question: are you adding your `<a>` after the page has loaded?  In the doc ready, (before the click handler) add: `alert($('#notif').length)` - what value do you get? What about `alert($("[id=notif]").length)`

Comment: I believe you have multiple hyperlinks with id `notif`, If so then change id to class in js and html

Comment: Nothing... strange.. looks like the code between <script> isnt even readed wtf... the code inside the script doesn't work at all, not even if I remove the onclick event

Comment: Where are you defining the `<script>` tag? inside a .js file?

Comment: @freedomn-m at the bottom of my php file before </body>

Comment: Try: `<script>alert("hey!")</script>` - are you also checking the console for errors?

Comment: ... worth checking, sometimes people put `<script>` tags in their js files :)

Comment: @freedomn-m that worked, so `$(document).ready(function () {` this is the issue

Comment: Ok, so try: `alert($)` - maybe you haven't included jquery before your script?

Comment: I got `function (a,b) {return new ` or something like that @freedomn-m

Comment: $ isn't always jquery - do you get the same with `alert(jQuery)` ?  (most likely the same) - and the jquery include is definitely before your `<script>` ?     What about:  `$(function() { alert("doc ready"); });` ?

Comment: Otherwise not sure I can help beyond that.

Comment: @freedomn-m I had some errors in other jquery files that were preventing document.ready, I fixed it, thank you alot, if you post as  a comment I'll mark it as solved

Comment: Glad you got it to work.